# Google is making 10 users when i upload new version of my app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

On every release google is starting 10+ instances of my app on their servers which results in 10 users created on the server.
How can i prevent that? Should i filter those request by ip or is any other method to fix that?
I am the only one developing and testing this app.

file format: aab, test type: Internal test

```cs
//pseudo code
var pac = PlayerPrefs.GetString("playerAccessCode");
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pac)) {
    //call http service and make new player
}
```

Comment: Where is this code being called? Can you share the monobehaviour?

Comment: @ErikOverflow i have canvas with main behaviour attached. It is taking care of initializing dependency injection, creating user on server and fetchind data from rest endpoints. I would need to place 2k+ lines of code for you to run my app.  It works fine when run in editor or uploaded directly to mobile phone. This problem only occur couple minutes after app is finished uploading 1) 2019-10-24 16:50:51 2)2019-10-24 16:51:09 3) 2019-10-24 16:51:10 4) 2019-10-24 16:51:14 5).. When all those requests are made new users are created as expected

Comment: Share the code that is invoking what you've shared above. You do not need to share the entire file, but right now your code is not reproducible.

Comment: @ErikOverflow i will try to extract it, but it won't be easy, cs scripts are over +14K LOC. It is working just fine except for the time after uploading to google play

Comment: If your scripts are that long, you should consider following better design principles. 10 scripts each doing 1 thing is more manageable than 1 script doing 10 things.

Comment: @ErikOverflow There are over 300 classes, main is only responsible for initialization. I could place some code, but it would require attaching dependencies too, extracting code to work without dependencies will be quite challenging

Comment: @ErikOverflow better question would be: Is this normal that google is starting my app on their servers and how to get rid of those extra "google made users"